# Add a Constant Variable to All Class Instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am working with AWS and have implemented a class to manipulate their virtual machines. I use the Python boto3 library to interact with AWS and need to set this variable for all of my class instances: `ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')`. Is there a way to set this once and thereafter anytime I create a new class instance it uses the same `ec2`?

I think I need to use some form of inheritance, but in this example I still need to specify `ec2` each time. E.g. `vm1 = myVM(ec2, 'hostname')`.

```
class ec2client:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self._ec2 = arg

class myVM(ec2client):
  def __init__(self, ec2, vmName):
    super().__init__(ec2)
```

How can I set `ec2` once in a class instance and then all future classes automatically use it?

(I'm calling my AWS instances 'VMs' here to differentiate from the Python use of instance.)

Comment: Class attributes: https://realpython.com/lessons/class-and-instance-attributes/

Comment: What if you want to define another subclass of `ec2client`? Will it have the same `arg` as all `myVM` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be nothing stopping you from doing this:

```
ec2_client_for_everyone = "I am an EC2 client"

class ec2client:
    _ec2 = ec2_client_for_everyone

    def __init__(self, arg):
        ...
```

Here _ec2 acts as a class attribute, and will be accessible inside each instance as `self._ec2`, or to the world as `ec2client._ec2`.

Comment: Thanks! 

This is what I did before when my class was included in the program itself. I have since moved the class into its own module which I now import into the original program.

Is there a more 'pythonic' way of doing this without constants? I'm totally happy with this suggested solution, but constants often feel like a crutch (to me).

Also, I using the _ec2 variable inside the class but outside of the defs, and kept getting a "name '_ec2' is not defined" error. I have just ended up using the constant defined outside of the class.

Comment: Oops. Ignore my sentence about the _ec2 variable. I overlooked your comment about the class attribute.

Comment: I can think of a couple other ways I might implement something similar, but it would really depend on what I would be planning on doing with it.  For example, if I were going to be writing unit tests against this class, rather than have a unit test accidentally call real EC2 functions, I might want to be able to pass in an optional mock to replace said _ec2 variable/attribute, but otherwise keep the default boto3/ec2 client.  That might look something like this:

`def __init__(self, ec2_client=boto3.client('ec2')):`